# How to apply a value from one row to all rows with the same ID in R

Tags: sql, r

I currently have a large data set that is in long format. I am hoping to apply a value only given at baseline (repeat_instance = 0) to all follow up instances (repeat_instance = 1, 2, 3+) based on the record_id.

While I cannot share the actual data I have created a simplified example below to illustrate the quesiton.

```
record_id <- c(1,1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,8,9,10,10,10)
repeat_instance <- c(0,1,2,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,2)
reason_for_visit <- c(1,NA,NA,1,2,1,NA,1,2,3,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA)
```

Current Format:

[image]

Desired Outcome:

[image]

I have seen solutions in Excel, however am not sure which formula may be useful in R.

Comment: in addition to akrun's solution, `zoo::na.locf` will fill "last observation carried forward" (locf).

Answer (score 0):

We can use `fill` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
fill(df1, reason_for_visit)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(record_id, repeat_instance, reason_for_visit)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I figured it had to be simple enough i was clearly googling the wrong thing!